# How to link folder/packages in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I come with this odd question, after look on the intelliJ forums I have no results.

I started to work in a project that has multiple gradle modules.

There is one module that has another module referencing it.

Lets say I have `ModuleA` with all my classes, each class I add on a new package appears also in `ModuleB`

When I checked on the folders of ModuleB I noticed a weird icon.

[image]

Checking the folder (right-click) I can see the option:

```
Go to Link Target
```

That basically takes me to ModuleA's folder `configuration`.

I could find no gradle configuration that makes these references or how to reproduce it.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Symbolic links and are created in Bash. This doesn't have anything to do with gradle.

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)